# woocommerce_rest_prepare_webhook not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the webhook data in my WooCommerce website but it's not working. I want to make sure if there is a certain product (with an ID of 20627), that this product will not show up in the response of the webhook. The problem is, it still shows this product in the "line_items" section of the webhook response. How come?

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'my_custom_webhook_handler' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_custom_webhook_handler' );
function my_custom_webhook_handler( $order_id ) {
    // get the order object
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // modify the webhook data
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_webhook', function( $response, $webhook ) use ( $order ) {
        // get the data that is being sent in the webhook
        $data = $response->get_data();

        // remove products from the data that match certain criteria
        foreach ( $data['line_items'] as $key => $line_item ) {
            $product_id = $line_item['product_id'];

            // check if the product matches the criteria to be removed
            if ( $product_id == 20627 ) {
                unset( $data['line_items'][ $key ] );
            }
        }

        // set the modified data back into the response object
        $response->set_data( $data );

        return $response;
    }, 10, 2 );
}
```

When I change "$response->set_data( $data );" to $response->set_data('');" for instance, it's even not showing the empty string.